# View logs recorded by workflow initiated scripts

Tags: aem, ecmascript-5

I am just starting in AEM, and I'm trying to set up a workflow with some basic scripting.  I have the most simple bit of ecmascript right now to log a variable.  My question is, where are the strings that i'm logging going to?  Is there a logger that i need to set up in configMgr, or is there an existing logfile?

```
function getParticipant() {
    log.info("assigning approvers...");
    var path = workItem.getWorkflowData().getPayload().toString();
    log.info("itemPath: " + path);
    return workItem.getWorkflow().getInitiator();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you check error.log file?

Comment: @SandeepKumar yes, it wasn't logging there.  Reinstalling fixed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default everything goes into your /log/error.log file unless configured otherwise.

log.info will only be visible if your logging is set to INFO level (or below, i.e. DEBUG etc.).

Comment: This led me down the right path, thanks!  I must have disconnected script logs at some point while messing with loggers, because my log wasn't going into error.log, even when i used log.error().  Reinstalling AEM fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

The below are the log files that are available in AEM

> **access.log** -- All access requests to AEM/CQ5 and the repository are registered here.
>
> **request.log** -- Each access request will be logged here with response
>
> **error.lo**g --  Error messages (of varying levels of severity like INFO, ERROR, DEBUG, etc.) are registered here.
>
> **stderr.log** --  error messages of varying levels of severity, generated during startup. By default the log level is set to Warning (WARN)
>
> **stdout.log** -- logger messages indicating events during start up.
>
> **upgrade.log** -- Provides a log of all upgrade operations that runs from the com.day.compat.codeupgrade and com.adobe.cq.upgradesexecutor packages.

To have your own logger file you can

> Add a logger configurations in AEM as shown below.

Example if I have to set `info` level logger for **my OSGi service (logger) `*com.mycompany.myrestservice*`**

**A Logging Writer writes all these messages to the physical file that you have defined.**

1. Log into Felix Console: `http://<host>:<port>/system/console/configMgr`
2. From "Factory Configurations", create "Apache Sling Logging Writer Configuration"
   [image: writer]
3. Set value of "Log File" to `"../logs/restservice.log"`
   Click on `"Save"`
   [image: Logging writer]

**A Logging Logger takes this message and formats it according to your specification.**

1. From "Factory Configurations", create "Apache Sling Logging Logger Configuration"
   [image: Create Logger]
2. Set value of "Log Level" to `"Info"`
3. Set value of "Log File" to `"../logs/restservice.log"`
4. Add "Logger" => `com.mycompany.myrestservice`
5. Click on `"Save"`
   [image: Sling Logging Logger]

> Below are the advantages that you will get by custom loggers

1. the specific logging level  -- i have set it to **Info**
2. the location of the individual log file --  i have set it to **/logs/restservice.log**
3. the number of versions to be kept -- i have set it to  **5**
4. version rotation; either maximum size or the time interval  -- i left to default value
5. the format to be used when writing the log messages -- i left to default value
6. the logger (the OSGi service supplying the log messages) -- i have set it to my OSGI service **com.mycompany.myrestservice**

Comment: _Very_ detailed response, but I am only logging ecmascript.  I can't create my own package for that can I?